# Prove that $\sum_{p \in \mathcal P} \frac1{p\ln \ln p}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1029640/153012) I've asked to decide the convergency of the series $\sum_{p \in \mathcal P} \frac1{p\ln p}$.

Now I ask you to show that the series

$$\sum_{p \in \mathcal P} \frac1{p\ln \ln p}$$

is divergent, where $\mathcal P$ is the set of all primes.

Maybe there is analogous ways as we've seen the proofs I referred above. I prefer techniques like what was used on the other problem, but of course any proof would by nice.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067539/prove-that-as-x-to-infty-sum-limits-p-leq-x-frac1p-log-log-p-ap/1067621#1067621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall again the prime number theorem, which gives that
$$ p_n \approx n\log n.$$
Then the sum we want can be compared to
$$ \sum_p \frac{1}{p \log \log p} \sim \sum_n \frac{1}{n\log n \log \log n}.$$
I claim this latter sum diverges based on the integral test for convergence.

> **Claim**: The following series diverges:
>   $$\sum_n \frac{1}{n \log n \log \log n} \tag{1}$$

*Proof*: Notice that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x \log x \log \log x}$ is a positive, decreasing, well-defined function for $x > 100$, say. So we may apply the integral test, and the sum in $(1)$ converges if and only if the integral below converges:
$$ \int_{100}^\infty \frac{1}{x \log x \log \log x} dx.$$
Perform the $u$-substitution $u = \log \log x$, and note that $du = \dfrac{dx}{x\log x}$. So this integral behaves like
$$ \int_{\log \log 100}^\infty \frac{1}{u} du = \left.\log u \right\rvert_{\log \log 100}^\infty \approx \log \log \log \infty,$$
which diverges. Note also that this means the integral (and therefore the sum) diverges like $\log \log \log n$, which is so unbelievably slow that it's hard to comprehend. But nonetheless, it diverges. $\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 3):

Long story short,
$$ p_n \leq C n \log n $$
by Chebyshev's theorem ($\pi(n)\geq D \frac{n}{\log n}$), hence the series is lower bounded by a multiple of
$$ \sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{1}{n\log n \log\log n}$$
that diverges due to [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) (applied twice).